# How to find the remainder of an AND operation on two sets in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two sets of countries, one of which is longer, and I'm trying to find the entries that don't feature in both lists.

(set(a) & set(b) this code gave me the entries that appear in both. Not(set(a) & set(b)) just returned false. I'm looking for a list

Answer (score 2):

In set theory, this is known as the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), and in Python, sets have a [`symmetric_difference` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference), so you could use

```py
set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))
```

or, as shorthand

```py
set(a) ^ set(b)
```